# Error while adding ssis code check extension - VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-2017, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I am trying to install the [SSIS code check Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MAQSoftware.SSISCodeCheck) from VS 2017

I am Getting error as

```
Prerequisites  Missing    : 

Identifier   : Microsoft.Net.Component.4.5.1.TargetingPack

Name         : .NET Framework 4.5.1 targeting pack
Version      : [16.0.28517.75,17.0)
```

I have tried to install the 4.5.1 framework alone, still same error.

Please suggest if you have come across this error or any alternative extension that we can use for the same.

Comment: What is the operating system version?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/guide-for-developers#to-install-the-net-framework-developer-pack-or-targeting-pack):

> A **targeting pack** lets your app target a specific version of .NET Framework when developing in Visual Studio and some other development environments. A **developer pack** includes a specific version of .NET Framework and its accompanying SDK **along with its corresponding targeting pack.**

To download the Microsoft .NET Framework developer pack, you can refer to the following page:

- [Download .NET Framework 4.5.1](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net451)

Comment: Hi Hadi,I have tried, not working though