# How can solve problem restart needed while install SSIS on Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, etl

I have Visual Studio 2019 Pro Version 16.11.10 and try to install SSIS 15.0.2000.170 but face with this error:

[image]

and this is the log file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a blocking point.

Just restart your machine.

Comment: i did that but same error

Comment: Hi @MHD, can you cop/paste the logs in here. Images are difficult to debug. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the log screenshot you provided, **the error was thrown while trying to install the *Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 Multi-Targeting pack (4.5.50932)*.**

As mentioned in [the SQL Server Integration Service projects extension page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects#offline), if you are trying to install the SSIS extension offline, you should make sure that the following prerequisites are installed with Visual Studio:

> - Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices"
>   Version="[16.0,)" DisplayName="C# and Visual Basic"
> - Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor" Version="[16.0,)" DisplayName="Visual Studio core editor"
> - Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.SSDT" Version="[16.0,)" DisplayName="SQL Server Data Tools"
> - Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.Net.Component.4.TargetingPack" Version="[16.0,)" DisplayName=".NET Framework 4 targeting pack"
> - Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.Net.Component.4.5.TargetingPack" Version="[16.0,)" DisplayName=".NET Framework 4.5 targeting pack"
> - Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.TargetingPack" Version="[16.0,)" DisplayName=".NET Framework 4.7 targeting pack"

You can download the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 Multi-Targeting pack from the [following link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40772).

---

#### Similar issues

- [Error while adding ssis code check extension - VS 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71078096/error-while-adding-ssis-code-check-extension-vs-2017/71079888#71079888)